# Firestore-Rules evaluation error on Timestamp Field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I wrote a firestore rule like this:

```js
function isPublished() {
  return !('publicationAt' in resource.data.keys()) ? true :
    debug(debug(request.time) >= debug(resource.data.publicationAt));
}
```

and in my app i´m saving several datetimes just with new Date();
Now, I´d like to get a list of all items that are published - but it gives me an evaluation error - with this debug:

> constraint_value {
> simple_constraints {
> comparator: LTE
> value {
> timestamp_value {
> seconds: 1669108946
> nanos: 684000000
> }
> }
> }
> }
>
> timestamp_value {   seconds: 1669108945   nanos: 727000000 }

Can someone give me a hint what I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you may be tempted to think that [Security Rules Language](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions) (SRL) is JavaScript because of the `function() {}` part, it is not. It is a special statically evaluated language that gets interpreted once without other common features like iteration.

Importantly, the SRL has no ternary operator:

```
<condition> ? <result-when-true> : <result-when-false>
```

Instead you must build your conditions as a sequence of Boolean tests making use of the [available helper methods and classes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules).

The equivalent in basic Boolean algebra of the ternary operator (when using short-circuiting operators like `&&` and `||`) is:

```
(<condition> && <result-when-true>) || (NOT(<condition>) && <result-when-false>)
```

Substituting in the value for `<result-when-true>`, we can reduce down your expression using [Boolean algebra laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws) (where the AND operator (`&&`) is `∧` and the OR operator (`||`) is `∨`):

```
(<condition> && <result-when-true>) || (NOT(<condition>) && <result-when-false>)

// replace <result-when-true> with TRUE, as in your question
(<condition> && TRUE) || (NOT(<condition>) && <result-when-false>)

// now remove the redundant "&& TRUE" (see "Identity of ∧")
<condition> || (NOT(<condition>) && <result-when-false>)

// now distribute the OR operator (see "Distributivity of ∨ over ∧")
(<condition> || NOT(<condition>)) && (<condition> || <result-when-false>)

// now replace (<condition> || NOT(<condition>)) because it will always be TRUE (see "Complementation 2")
TRUE && (<condition> || <result-when-false>)

// now remove the redundant "TRUE &&" like before (see "Identity of ∧")
<condition> || <result-when-false>
```

Subsituting in the parts from your question, this leaves us with:

```js
   !('publicationAt' in resource.data.keys())
|| debug(debug(request.time) >= debug(resource.data.publicationAt))
```

You can also simplify `'publicationAt' in resource.data.keys()` to just `'publicationAt' in resource.data` (as the `in` operator handles what you were expecting for [`rules.Map` objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map)), giving us:

```js
   !('publicationAt' in resource.data)
|| debug(debug(request.time) >= debug(resource.data.publicationAt));
```

This means the correct form of your SRL function would look like:

```js
function isPublished() {
  return !('publicationAt' in resource.data)
      || debug(debug(request.time) >= debug(resource.data.publicationAt));
}
```

Comment: great explained! thank you very much @samthecodingman